# change button background using another button: Android

Tags: android, tags, android-drawable

I want to change button1 background when button2 is pressed and then when button2 is pressed again i want button1 to change back to original background. So basically everytime i presss button2, button1 will change background back and forth.

I created custom buttons xml which are on a drawable folder.

This is part of my code:

```
button1.setTag("0");
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (button1.getTag() == "0") {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customButton_layout1); 
            button1.setTag("1");                      
        }

        if (button1.getTag() == "1") {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customButton_layout2);
            button1.setTag("0");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did adding an else actually fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `else` before second `if`.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing strings you should use `.equals()`, so you should change `button1.getTag() == "0"` to `button1.getTag().equals("0")`

Answer (score 0):

This way button will always have second background because after first if statement second will be also executed.

Just put else before second if statement and it should work.

Also use equals when comparing strings just as Uxonith suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple. Try it this way:

```
Button but1,but2;
int count = 0;
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

count++;
if(count%2==0){
but2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customButton_layout1); }
else{
but2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customButton_default);
}
}
d});
```

Here counter toggles the drawable of but2.